# Stop a Qthread PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qthread

I've tried several methods to stop a Qthread, but none seem to work. When I look at the Call Stack, the thread has not ended, and while click again, another thread starts, thus getting infinite active threads and consuming more unnecessary memory. I tried to put terminate() and quit() and nothing stops the thread. So I also tried all of them together and no result

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import time
import sys

class MyThread(QThread):
    def run(self):
        x=0
        print("Starting...")
        while x<5:
            time.sleep(1.5)
            print("Running...")
            x=x+1

    def close(self):
        self.isRunning=False
        self.terminate()
        self.wait()
        self.quit()
        self.wait()
        print("Done")

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self):
         super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()
         self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
         self.btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(77, 30, 50, 30))
         self.btn.setText("CLICK")
         self.btn.clicked.connect(self.doSomething)


     def doSomething(self,event):
         self.worker=MyThread()
         self.worker.setTerminationEnabled(True)
         self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.close)
         self.worker.start() 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Connecting to what you do in `close()` with the `finished` signal is completely pointless: at that point the thread *is* finished, so any call to `terminate()` (which is discouraged, as clearly written in the documentation) or `quit()` is useless. You probably want to call `deleteLater()` when the thread has finished. Besides, your thread code does absolutely nothing, so there's nothing to stop there. If you want help in stopping a thread, please provide a valid [mre] to work with and explain what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Updated with a working example

Comment: Use a basic instance attribute with a boolean (eg. `self.keepRunning = True`), and check it periodically in `run()`. When you want to stop it, just set it to `False`, then quit it.

Comment: can you give an example? I tried to apply the modification you said, but I got no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem using threading native library and with pyqtSignal. When clicking on the button, it loses its connection and starts the thread. After the end of the loop in the thread, a signal is issued and thus returning the connection to the button. This way, it prevents the user from clicking the button several times.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import time
import sys
import threading

class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
     signal=pyqtSignal(str)
     def __init__(self):
         super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()
         self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
         self.btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(77, 30, 50, 30))
         self.btn.setText("CLICK")
         self.signal.connect(self.signalResponse)
         self.btn.clicked.connect(self.doSomething)

     def doSomething(self,event):
         print("Starting...")
         self.btn.disconnect()
         worker=threading.Thread(target=self.worker)
         worker.start()

     def signalResponse(self,response):
         if response=="Finished":
            self.btn.clicked.connect(self.doSomething)
            print(response)

     def worker(self):
        x=0
        while x<5:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("Running...")
            x=x+1
        self.signal.emit("Finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```